# Sendmail Message-ID check Ruleset

Tags: sendmail

We experienced an issue with automated email messages from a financial institution being rejected where the following was logged:

<snip> ruleset=CheckMessageId <snip> reject=553 5.0.0 Header Error

The associated Sendmail ruleset shows the following:

```
R< $+ @ $+ >        $@ OK
```

I found that the institution's message-id did not contain the angle brackets.  In order to permit messages from their domain, would I add the following rule?

```
R $+ @ example.com        $@ OK
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a workaround that will help you.